# Custom Repeat Password Validation Error in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-validation

I am learning Angular2 Custom Validation for Repeat password for registration form from reference scotch.io site:
https://scotch.io/@ibrahimalsurkhi/match-password-validation-with-angular-2

Here is my code for validator.compare.ts:

```
import {AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';
export class PasswordValidation {

    static MatchPassword(AC: AbstractControl) {
       let password = AC.get('password').value; // to get value in input tag
       let confirmPassword = AC.get('confirmPassword').value; // to get value in input tag
        if(password != confirmPassword) {
            console.log('false');
            AC.get('confirmPassword').setErrors( {MatchPassword: true} )
        } else {
            console.log('true');
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

And Registration.ts:

```
import { OnInit, Component } from "@angular/core";
import { UserModel } from "../../_model/usermodel";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { PasswordValidation } from '../../_utilities/_validations/validator.compare';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './_componant/registration/registration.html'
})

export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
    user: UserModel = { id: 0, email: "", password: "", username: "" };
    myform : FormGroup;
    submitted : boolean = false;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.myform = new FormGroup({
            username : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
            password : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
            confirmPassword: new FormControl("", Validators.required)
        },{ validator: PasswordValidation.MatchPassword })
    }
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

I am getting following Error:

> Argument of type '{ validator: (AC: AbstractControl) => any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'validator' does not exist in type 'ValidatorFn'

I've attached screenshot for more clarity.
[image]

Here are have project folder hierarchy for path:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import { PasswordValidation } from 'YOUR/CLASS/PATH/_utilities/_validations/validator.compare';

    this.myform = new FormGroup({
                username : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
                password : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
                confirmPassword: new FormControl("", Validators.required)
            },{ validator: MatchPassword });
```

The error say that you are not pointing to a right method,
Simply call the function if you path is right.

Comment: I've attached folder hierarchy to understand path. I think I've wrote correct path, have I?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check how build a validatorFn. https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidationErrors

Define returned type of your method.